# Update current version of php by keeping apache version same on debian5

Tags: php, apache, debian

i am using php's 5.3.7 version  so how to update current php version supported by linux debian server and apache.

i am using linux debian version 5.0.1
            apache version apache2.2.20.

so can i update php version.

Comment: You might want to consider to upgrade your OS. Debian 5 hasn't been supported for 6 years and 5.0.1 is 9 (!) years old. The newest Debian version is 9.4. https://wiki.debian.org/DebianLenny#Release_and_updates

Comment: i do not want to update debian and apache version

Comment: That makes it extremely hard. Aside from the fact that your server will pretty much be a sitting duck for any hacker, I don't know if anyone compiles binaries for Debian 5 anymore.

Comment: @shriyashLakhe why You reject moving to latest debian or ubuntu? You have no experience with installing new os and web stack? All debians has package called: `tasksel`, simply call it and pick LAMP and everything will be installed.

Comment: no i dont have  experience  on linux debian  so just want to know that it is possible to update php version for above  configuration .

Comment: Downlod a recent PHP version and compile it on your system.  Don`t try to find a compiled package on such an old OS.

Comment: thanks..  but there is need to update apache version

Answer (score 0):

You can add the lenny back-ports repository to */etc/apt/sources.list*. But I doubt that the repo contains anything significantly newer.

Or you could try to compile php from source. But probably Debian Lenny does not even contain the necessary dependencies to compile today's php.

You have missed so many security fixes that you should not dare to run a web server on the system. The most viable option is a clean install.